# Why is my Bash sed command ( sed -e "s/-*[a-zA-Z\-]* / /g" ) removing characters after dot?

Tags: bash, sed

I am making a simple bash script for building cpp, and I am having problem while separating the arguments using sed, the command in the title is removing every character after a dot " . " and I don't understand the reason

This is what I have in my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
Arguments=$@
echo $Arguments
Files=$(echo $Arguments | sed -e "s/-*[a-zA-Z\-]* / /g")
echo $Files
```

When running "./build.sh --linux --clean --no-questions main.cpp build/linux/main", this is what I get in the output

```
--linux --clean --no-questions main.cpp build/linux/main
main. build/linux/main
```

Why is this removing the "cpp" after the period? It doesn't make much sense for me, I thought I was only matching for letters and dashes.

Ok it was pretty simple. Barman nailed it.

Comment: You told it to remove all letters before space.

Comment: How do you run your script?

Comment: @Cyrus first line outputted is the given arguments. I ran it like so: ./build.sh --linux --clean --no-questions main.cpp build/linux/main

Comment: Since you have `-*` at the beginning, this will match when there are no `-` characters at the beginning. If a hyphen is required, get rid of the `*`.

Comment: @Barman hm I think I see it now, thank you

Comment: But I think you also want the `-` to be at the beginning of the argument, don't you? So you need to match a space or `^` before it.

Comment: Your regex matches zero or more dashes (`-*`) followed by zero or more letters, digits or dashes (`[a-zA-Z-]*`) followed by one space and replaces the matching fragment with one space. The fragment `"cpp "` from `"main.cpp "` matches the regex.

Comment: Otherwise it will match the `-bar` part of `foo-bar`

Comment: BTW, I don't think `sed` understands escaping the `-` inside `[]`. So it's also matching a literal backslash.

Comment: @Barman  It seems to be working now with Files=$(echo $Arguments | sed -e "s/-[a-zA-Z\-]*/ /g"), this way I get only the undashed arguments. Removing the * did the trick Thanks again everyone!

Comment: Please show the script's input.

Comment: @agc I did (:  It's in the first output line

Comment: Please show the script's input **separate** from the output.

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the problem is you have `-*` at the beginning.
So it matches when there is 0 or more `-`.

A simple fix is to use this:
`s/-[a-zA-Z\-]* / /g`

So your code becomes:

````
#!/bin/bash
Arguments=$@
echo $Arguments
Files=$(echo $Arguments | sed -e "s/-[a-zA-Z\-]* / /g")
echo $Files```
````